# How to make this loop Ctrl+C-interruptible?

Tags: shell-script, signals

```
# wait for host to become online
while true; do
    ping host -c 1 -w 3 > /dev/null && break;
    sleep 1
done
```

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, the ping receives it and exits with exit code 1 (the same as if host down).
How do I do this correctly?

Workaround: `sleep 1 || break` and pressing ^C twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
trap "exit 1" INT

while true; do
    ping host -c 1 -w 3 > /dev/null && break;
    sleep 1
done

trap - INT # restore handler
```

Comment: Shouldnt be trap "exit" INT?

Comment: The *default* action on SIGINT is to exit, so you don't have to do this unless you have already trapped it.

Comment: @psusi Try running it. You can replace it host with `localhost` and temporarily disable pings with `sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.icmp_echo_ignore_all=1
` to simulate it being unresponsive. The version without the trap doesn't reliably exit on `^C`; the version with that trap does.

Answer (score 1):

Just don't write your loop so weird.

```sh
until ping host -c 1 -w 3
do    sleep 1
done  >/dev/null
```

Doing the above will require at *most* two `^C` keystrokes in a row to exit the loop - and that's because of `sleep`. But if you layer it one more time:

```
sh -c '
    until ping host -c 1 -w 3
    do    sleep 1
    done' >/dev/null
```

...you won't need even the two.